# Weird for loop statement

Tags: python, for-loop

I saw this for loop and I didn't quite understood why the last print is 2.
Why it isn't 3 ?

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3]

for a[-1] in a:
    print(a[-1])
```

out:

```
0
1
2
2
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `for` loop uses `a[-1]` as a *target variable*, assigning each value from the input iterable:

```
for <target> in <iterable>
```

The `for` loop assigns each value in the `a` list to that one target, `a[-1]`. That happens to *also* be the last element in that same list.

So the list *changes* with each step through the loop:

```
>>> a = [0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> for a[-1] in a:
...     print a
...
[0, 1, 2, 0]  # assigned a[0] == 0 to a[-1] (or a[3])
[0, 1, 2, 1]  # assigned a[1] == 1 to a[-1]
[0, 1, 2, 2]  # assigned a[2] == 2 to a[-1]
[0, 1, 2, 2]  # assigned a[3] == 2 (since the previous iteration) to a[-1]
```

The one-but-last iteration assigns puts `a[2]` into `a[3]` (or `a[-2]` into `a[-1]`), and that is why, when the last iteration takes place, you see `2` *again*.

See the [`for` loop grammar](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement); it takes a generic *target_list* for the assignment target, just like an [assigment statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements). You are not limited to just simple names in assignments, and neither are you in a `for` loop.